# Battleship game advice in java

Tags: java, swing, sockets, user-interface

Currently I'm trying to create a battleship game in java. Two player connect to the server, place there ships and start the game. I have created a server and a client. I don't know how to transfer one player's shot coordinates from one player to another. Ship coordinates are stored in List at client side. Which is the best solution for player communication? Maybe player ship coordinates should be sent to server, and the second player will check them on server? Or I should stay with the idea that player sends to another player coordinates and gets the result? Maybe somebody will have a better idea.

Comment: I would have thought to send all positions to the server and get it to send out "hit" and "miss" reports to both sides, in response to each "firing".  You could use a restful web service and send the data with something like jaxb

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want people to cheat, you keep all coordinate data on the server.  The clients request coordinate data from the server.

Your clients send messages to the server and the server provides a response.  That's the only way that you as a player know that the server is still connected.

The content of the messages and the content of the response are up to you.

Answer (score 2):

When started, send the ship-coords to the server. (Don't store them on client. A battleship game does not requires ultra-fast-speed, so its better if its on the server.) Then, let the server send a "your turn"-packet to the client who should begin. The client chooses a shoot-location, wich is transferred to the server. Server checks if ship or water, and sends this data to both clients. Next turn-packet, and so on...

Hope it helps :)

PS: I would use the KryoNet library!https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for communication right now? Since you taged your question with socket I guess you are using plain ip sockets. Maybe you have a look ar [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/). It's easy to set-up and you can use it almost like a plain java call.

This way updating the shot's of a player is just a matter of calling a method.